# Moving arrow helper away from an object

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

As you can see the two arrow helper are moved inner instead of move farther away from the object. How can I move it away from the object?

Here's my code

```
var startx = wall.getStartX();
    var starty = wall.getStartY();
    var endx = wall.getEndX();
    var endy = wall.getEndY();

    // this section sets how far the arrow should move away
    // this is the part where I'm having trouble
    if (wall.getWallOrientation() == 'horizontal') {
        starty += 50;
        endy += 50;
    } else {
        // vertical 
        startx += 50;
        endx += 50;
    }

    // define start and end point of dimension
    var from = new THREE.Vector3(startx, 0, starty);
    var to = new THREE.Vector3(endx, 0, endy);

    var direction = to.clone().sub(from);
    var length = direction.length();

    var hex = 0x0;
    var arrorGroupHelper = new THREE.Group();
    arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), from, length, hex, 10, 10));
    arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.negate(), to, length, hex, 10, 10));
```

Thank you and more power.

Comment: You need to know not only if it's horizontal or vertical, but also which side a helper belongs to (top, bottom, left, right). Thus you'll be able to set the sign of your offsets.

Comment: I see. so does a helper has this property once it is created? or is there a way to compute what is top, bottom, left, right based on points?

Comment: You can consider to create an instance of [Box2](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box2) for your wall. You should then be able to derive all four sides from the `min` and `max` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. First I get the center of the line then compute the angle. This way I know where should it move away.

```
var degrees = Utils.angleAccurate(center.x, center.y, lineCenterPoint.x, lineCenterPoint.y);

        var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
        var x = startx + Math.cos(radians) * 30;
        var y = starty + Math.sin(radians) * 30;

var orientation = edge.wall.getWallOrientation();
        if (orientation == 'horizontal') {
            starty = y;
            endy = y;
        } else if (orientation == 'vertical') {
            // vertical 
            startx = x;
            endx = x;
        }
```